# Makefile cannot find module in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile

I have a little application on Python3 but it won't run because of module not found. I added `__init__.py` for all the folders already but it doesn't work. I'm wondering why.

Here's my structure

```
my_project
  |- __init__.py
  |
  |-- folder
        |-code.py
        |- __init__.py
  |
  |-- Makefile
  |-- scripts
        |- import_data.py
```

Here's My Makefile

```
test:
    py.test tests/*.py

create_graph:
    python scripts/import_data.py
```

And here's my import_data.py

```
from folder.code import method

import csv

method()
# doing something here
```

When I run `make create_graph` It gives me this.

```
python scripts/import_data.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/import_data.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder.code import method
ImportError: No module named 'folder'
make: *** [create_graph] Error 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `import_data.py` script is run, the `sys.path` has `my_project/scripts` in it, but not `my_project` , hence python is not able to locate `folder` package in `sys.path` .

You should try adding the `my_project` folder into the `PYTHONPATH` variable , this would allow you to access `folder.code` from anywhere. Example for `BASH` -

```
export PYTHONPATH=<path/to/my_project>:$PYTHONPATH
```

If you cannot make such environment variable changes , then programmatically, before trying to import `folder.code` , you can add the `my_project` folder to `sys.path` variable. For that you can use `__file__` to get the filename of the script, and then get the directory name from that using `os.path.dirname()` and then get its parent using `os.path.join` and `os.path.abspath` Example your `import_data.py` may look like -

```
import sys
import os.path
parent = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')) #this should give you absolute location of my_project folder.
sys.path.append(parent)
from folder.code import method
import csv

method()
```