# No module found when executing Python program directly or from a Makefile, but works fine when running using "python"

Tags: python, makefile

I have a python program that uses the ElementTree module. When I run my program using "python" like the following...

```
python myprogram.py
```

...it works fine. But when I run it from inside a Makefile (same command as above inside the Makefile), it says ***"ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree"***. I also see the same error when I add "#!/usr/bin/env python" on the first line and try executing the myprogram.py directly.

I am mainly interested in being able to run my program from a Makefile (whether using the "python" command or executing directly doesn't matter as long as I can execute from a Makefile).

I have found 2 thread in SO, namely...

1. [ImportError: No module named when module is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828319/importerror-no-module-named-when-module-is-there)
2. [Makefile cannot find module in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385154/makefile-cannot-find-module-in-python3)

...but these 2 thread talk about importing non-standard (ie custom made modules). How do I fix this issue given that I am using standard python modules and given that I want to be able to run from a Makefile?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?  If so, rather than using `env` then I suggest you use the full path to the version you intend to use.

Comment: @cdarke, Thanks a lot! I did have two versions installed and did what you said and now I can run directly AND from a makefile. So this fixed my issue. I don't understand -why- this resolved the issue though. Also can you please make this into an answer instead of a comment so I can accept as answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Arash in `make`, the `$PATH` is probably set up different than in your shell.

Comment: You have a custom `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` set in your shell startup scripts most likely. `make` is running `/bin/sh` in a non-interactive mode so it isn't going to read those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments.  There is more than one version of Python installed.  The default path to modules is within the current python's directory structure, therefore the wrong directory was being searched.

In interactive mode it could be that the PATH environment variable is set in a startup file.  There are other possibilities with startup files, for example an alias called  "python" might be set (aliases are not exported).

The solution is to explicitly use the full path name of the required python.

This illustrates an issue with using `#!/usr/bin/env` in scripts - it assumes that the environment is always correct for the required version of python.  There are security concerns with using `env` as well.